# Convert Multiple JSON Objects to JSON Array

Tags: json, mongodb, python-3.x

I have generated a JSON file from data source which is of the format.
`{}{}{}`
I wish to convert this format to comma separated JSON Array as.  `[{},{},{}]`.
End goal is to push the JSON data `[{},{},{}]` to MongoDB. 
My pythoin solution (although naive) looks something like this:

```
def CreateJSONArrayFile(filename):
 print('Opening file with JSON data')
 with open(filename) as data_file:
    raw_data = data_file.read()
    tweaked_data = raw_data.replace('}{', '}^|{')
 split_data = tweaked_data.split('^|')
 outfile = open('split_data.json', 'w')
 outfile.write('[')
 for item in split_data:
    outfile.write("%s," % item)
 outfile.write(']')
 print('split_data.json Created with JSON Array')
```

The above code is giving me wrong results. 
Can you please help me optimize the solution? Please let me know if you need more details from my end.

Comment: Can you convert to a dictionary, iterate through key/value pairs, and convert back to JSON? (or leave as dicts). So that you get the best help, can you include a simplified sample of your source and results?

Comment: Since you generated this `{}{}{}` format from a data source, probably easiest would be to generate the *desired* format from the data source, appending each `dict` to a `list` -- rather than hassle with reformatting the undesired format

Answer (score 0):

I'm with davedwards on this one, but if not an option -- I think this gets you what you are after.

```
myJson = """{"This": "is", "a": "test"} {"Of": "The", "Emergency":"Broadcast"}"""
myJson = myJson.replace("} {", "}###{")
new_list = myJson.split('###')
print(new_list)
```

yields:

```
['{"This": "is", "a": "test"}', '{"Of": "The", "Emergency":"Broadcast"}']
```

Not saying it is the most elegant way : )